# Finite inner direct sums of simple modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Within a proof given in my abstract algebra lecture, we conclude that for any Ring $R$ and any $R$-module $M$ any finite sum of simple submodules $(M_i)_{i\le n}$ is an inner direct sum already, if any two of those submodules intersect trivially, i.e. $\forall i\neq j:\;M_i\cap M_j=\{0\}\implies \sum^n_{i=1}M_i=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n M_i$.

I am very unsure about this 'fact' since I cannot prove it. Is this even true? Can anyone outline a proof if it is?

EDIT: My main concern is that for $n>2$ I cannot prove that $M_i\cap\sum^n_{\overset{j=1}{i\neq j}}M_j=\{0\}$ for every $i$. As far as I know that is the required condition for a sum to be direct.

Comment: Is every sum of one-dimensional subspaces of a vector space direct?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "unique." Do you mean non-isomorphic?

Comment: Uniqueness in this case is meant as any two of them intersect trivially. What I cannot prove is that, given this intersection property, for any one simple module the intersection of the module with the sum of the remaining (finitely many) modules is also trivial. If $n=2$ this becomes obvious, but I cannot prove it for bigger $n$. Non-isomorphic is definitely not given, since I am looking at isomorphic modules within the proof I'm trying to understand.

Comment: In that case the statement is not true, as the vector space example shows.

Comment: Sorry for not acknowledging that counterexample sooner, I was stupid enough to only consider the vector space example with 2 subspaces, which is obviously no counter example. Thinking about this further has shown my stupidity, sorry about that. Thanks to everyone, even though this doesn't help me understanding the given proof (which might not even be correct).

Answer (score 2):

We can do this inductively in the case where they are pairwise non-isomorphic.

Assume that any family of $n -1$ pairwise non-isomorphic simple sub-modules of $M$ form a direct sum.

Then we may rewrite $M_i\cap\sum^n_{\overset{j=1}{i\neq j}}M_j= M_i\cap\bigoplus^n_{\overset{j = 1}{j\neq i}} M_j$

Since 
$M_i$ is simple it would mean that either $ M_i\cap\bigoplus^n_{\overset{j = 1}{j\neq i}} M_j = \{0\}$
or 
$M_i\cap\bigoplus^n_{\overset{j = 1}{j\neq i}} M_j= M_i$.

Now $M_i\cap\bigoplus^n_{\overset{j = 1}{j\neq i}} M_j= M_i$ 
implies that 
$M_i$ has an isomorphic copy in $\bigoplus^n_{\overset{j = 1}{j\neq i}} M_j$, which is impossible by the uniqueness theorem for semisimple modules.